# size and resolution of tikz image when using spy library

Tags: tikz-pgf, size, spy, resolution

I am using the spy library of the tikz package and I would like to avoid pixilation of the zoomed area while at the same time keep the size of the generated pdf file as small as possible.

Let's say that I would like to end up with a pdf document which has a 150dpi. If `\textwidth` is 15cm, and I would like to add an bitmap image (let's say jpeg) spanning the entire page using a simple `includegraphics` command, I would need to prepare a jpeg image with a width of 15cm and 150dpi (for example in GIMP).

If, however I am using the spy library of the tikz package in order to magnify a portion of the image by a factor of 3, then I would imagine that in order to end up with a document that has 150dpi, I would need to prepare a jpeg image with a width of 45cm and 150dpi. Then when including the image in the tikzpicture environment I would use the command

```
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image.jpg}
```

which would essentially shrink the image to 15cm (or equivalently increasing the resolution to 450dpi). Then when I use the spy command with `magnification=3`, the portion of the image that I am spying on would be brought down to the resolution of 150dpi that I want. Is that correct, or am I missing something?

If the above is correct, then if I am spying on a very small portion of the entire image (let's say an area of 1/20 of the image) but using a very large magnification factor (let's say a magnification of 20), that would mean that I would need to have the entire jpeg image 20 times larger just so that the magnified portion appears at the desired dpi. Since I am magnifying only 1/20th of the image, this would mean that I am not using 19/20th of the large image, but it would still be incorporated in the pdf document generated by latex, thus bloating up the size of the compiled pdf file in MB.

Is my understanding correct and if it is, is there a way to get around this problem?

Comment: I do not know if it is really like that. -but a solution would be NOT to use spy. Insert the picture in the desired resolution and insert another higher resolution picture. The higher resolution picture can be scaled up with `scale` and clipped with the `viewport` options of `\includegraphics`.

Comment: Yes, I agree with @hpekristiansen --- `spy` is really for scalable graphics, not for bitmap. If you have a bitmap and go to high magnification, the best option is doing that by hand.

Comment: @hpekristiansen and Rmano, thank you for your replies!